# How to translate the data to a "crosstab" style using js and mui x-data grid table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crosstab

I need to display the data in a table in [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BCbc.png) from [what I have now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUhFR.png)

The data object I'm getting looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp713.png)

I am using mui x-data grid table to display the table:

```
<DataGrid
    rows={recon_rows} 
    columns={recon_columns} 
/>
```

And I'm getting the data displayed in the table in the current state with this code:

```
var recon_rows = [];
var recon_columns = [];
var setHeaders = new Set();
var setDate = new Set();

for(let i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
  setHeaders.add(reportData[i].hdrname);
  setDate.add(reportData[i].recondate);
}

recon_columns = [
  { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Date', minWidth: 100 },
  { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Charge', minWidth: 100 },
];

for(var headers of setHeaders) {
  recon_columns.push({
    field: headers,
    headerName: headers,
    minWidth: 150
  });

  for(var dates of setDate) {
    var charge = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
      if(reportData[i].hdrname === headers && reportData[i].recondate === dates) {
        charge += reportData[i].entryqty;
        recon_rows.push({
          id: Math.random(dates),
          col1: dates,
          col2: charge,
          [headers]: charge
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions of how adjust the code to get it display the dates in a date column only once per date and for the rest of the data to follow horizontally I would highly appreciate it. Charge should be the sum of all the other cells in the same row.

[Here's the link for the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toolbargrid-demo-mui-x-forked-nuquoz?file=/demo.js)

I'm adding the data object from the image above:

```
[
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 1,
    "entryqty": 16,
    "entrycharge": 160,
    "entryseq": 10001,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 1,
    "entryqty": 5,
    "entrycharge": 50,
    "entryseq": 10001,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 1,
    "entryqty": 12,
    "entrycharge": 120,
    "entryseq": 10001,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 2,
    "entryqty": 7,
    "entrycharge": 56,
    "entryseq": 10002,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 2,
    "entryqty": 2,
    "entrycharge": 16,
    "entryseq": 10002,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 2,
    "entryqty": 2,
    "entrycharge": 16,
    "entryseq": 10002,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-2S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 3,
    "entryqty": 14,
    "entrycharge": 168,
    "entryseq": 10003,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 3,
    "entryqty": 25,
    "entrycharge": 300,
    "entryseq": 10003,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 3,
    "entryqty": 3,
    "entrycharge": 36,
    "entryseq": 10003,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Major-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 4,
    "entryqty": 8,
    "entrycharge": 68,
    "entryseq": 10004,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 4,
    "entryqty": 12,
    "entrycharge": 102,
    "entryseq": 10004,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 1,
    "entryid": 4,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 8.5,
    "entryseq": 10004,
    "hdrname": "SERV-Minor-34S"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 2,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 3.7,
    "entryseq": 20002,
    "hdrname": "Wheel-Swl"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 2,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 3.7,
    "entryseq": 20002,
    "hdrname": "Wheel-Swl"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 3,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 4.25,
    "entryseq": 20003,
    "hdrname": "Castor"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 5,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 0.6,
    "entryseq": 20005,
    "hdrname": "Hinge"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 5,
    "entryqty": 2,
    "entrycharge": 1.2,
    "entryseq": 20005,
    "hdrname": "Hinge"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 9,
    "entryqty": 7,
    "entrycharge": 28,
    "entryseq": 20009,
    "hdrname": "rp-Shelf"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 9,
    "entryqty": 40,
    "entrycharge": 160,
    "entryseq": 20009,
    "hdrname": "rp-Shelf"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 9,
    "entryqty": 25,
    "entrycharge": 100,
    "entryseq": 20009,
    "hdrname": "rp-Shelf"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 12,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 1.3,
    "entryseq": 20012,
    "hdrname": "Plate"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 13,
    "entryqty": 59,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20013,
    "hdrname": "rp-Base"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 13,
    "entryqty": 11,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20013,
    "hdrname": "rp-Base"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 13,
    "entryqty": 35,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20013,
    "hdrname": "rp-Base"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 14,
    "entryqty": 39,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20014,
    "hdrname": "rp-Side"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 14,
    "entryqty": 90,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20014,
    "hdrname": "rp-Side"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 14,
    "entryqty": 10,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20014,
    "hdrname": "rp-Side"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 15,
    "entryqty": 5,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20015,
    "hdrname": "rp-FxCast"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 15,
    "entryqty": 23,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20015,
    "hdrname": "rp-FxCast"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 15,
    "entryqty": 3,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20015,
    "hdrname": "rp-FxCast"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 16,
    "entryqty": 35,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20016,
    "hdrname": "rp-WhPlt"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 16,
    "entryqty": 44,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20016,
    "hdrname": "rp-WhPlt"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 16,
    "entryqty": 10,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20016,
    "hdrname": "rp-WhPlt"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 17,
    "entryqty": 11,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20017,
    "hdrname": "rp-AFrm"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 17,
    "entryqty": 34,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20017,
    "hdrname": "rp-AFrm"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 17,
    "entryqty": 39,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20017,
    "hdrname": "rp-AFrm"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 18,
    "entryqty": 16,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20018,
    "hdrname": "Clean-Whl"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 18,
    "entryqty": 64,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20018,
    "hdrname": "Clean-Whl"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 18,
    "entryqty": 143,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20018,
    "hdrname": "Clean-Whl"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 19,
    "entryqty": 19,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20019,
    "hdrname": "rp-Gate"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-21",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 19,
    "entryqty": 2,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20019,
    "hdrname": "rp-Gate"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 19,
    "entryqty": 6,
    "entrycharge": 0,
    "entryseq": 20019,
    "hdrname": "rp-Gate"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-19",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 31,
    "entryqty": 2,
    "entrycharge": 1,
    "entryseq": 20031,
    "hdrname": "sv-Wheel"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 33,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 2,
    "entryseq": 20033,
    "hdrname": "sv-Shelf"
},
{
    "recondate": "2022-07-20",
    "entryclass": 2,
    "entryid": 34,
    "entryqty": 1,
    "entrycharge": 0.5,
    "entryseq": 20034,
    "hdrname": "sv-Gate"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the structure of the data & how the tables are displayed in your case I believe you need to do this:

```js
var recon_rows = [];
var recon_columns = [];
var setHeaders = new Set();
var setDate = new Set();

for(let i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
  setHeaders.add(reportData[i].hdrname);
  setDate.add(reportData[i].recondate);
}

recon_columns = [
  { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Date', minWidth: 100 },
  { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Charge', minWidth: 100 },
];

for(var headers of setHeaders) {
  recon_columns.push({
    field: headers,
    headerName: headers,
    minWidth: 150
  });

  for(var dates of setDate) {
    var charge = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
      const date = reportData[i].recondate;
      if(reportData[i].hdrname === headers && date === dates) {
        charge += reportData[i].entryqty;

        // look up for existing row
        const existingRow = recon_rows.find((row) => row.col1 === date);

        // if we did not find the row
        if(!existingRow){
          // create it
          recon_rows.push({
            id: Math.random(dates),
            col1: dates,
            col2: charge,
            [headers]: charge
          });
        } else {
          // if we did find the row, add respective column
          existingRow[headers] = charge;
          // adjust charges
          existingRow.col2 += charge;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data output will then look like:

```json
[
  {
    id: 0.4279088926926955,
    col1: '2022-07-19',
    col2: 522,
    'SERV-Major-2S': 16,
    'SERV-Minor-2S': 7,
    'SERV-Major-34S': 25,
    'SERV-Minor-34S': 12,
    'Wheel-Swl': 1,
    Hinge: 1,
    'rp-Shelf': 40,
    Plate: 1,
    'rp-Base': 59,
    'rp-Side': 90,
    'rp-FxCast': 23,
    'rp-WhPlt': 44,
    'rp-AFrm': 39,
    'Clean-Whl': 143,
    'rp-Gate': 19,
    'sv-Wheel': 2
  },
  {
    id: 0.7232027224695496,
    col1: '2022-07-21',
    col2: 81,
    'SERV-Major-2S': 5,
    'SERV-Minor-2S': 2,
    'SERV-Major-34S': 3,
    'SERV-Minor-34S': 1,
    'rp-Shelf': 7,
    'rp-Base': 11,
    'rp-Side': 10,
    'rp-FxCast': 3,
    'rp-WhPlt': 10,
    'rp-AFrm': 11,
    'Clean-Whl': 16,
    'rp-Gate': 2
  },
  ...
];
```

I'm assuming here that in your "desired" screenshot you made a mistake in the "Charge" column, because it seems like it should be `sum` of all the other columns (except the date one).

Comment: Thanks man it's exactly what I was looking for and yes, you are right about the charge column as well ;)
I would upvote if I could but my rep is too low :(